# Turn a blog spot template into its own page

Tags: html, css, blogspot

Not sure if this is possible,

How could I get a nice blogspot template and turn it into its own html css website?
 I have the main html page and css but when I upload to my server its missing tons of styling.

This is my example. http://inspiro-veethemes.blogspot.in/ I would like to use that layout but I do NOT have blog spot. Is this even possible?

Comment: Probably because you didn't grab the CSS files too. Hope you aren't ripping off other's ideas...... inspired by is one thing (and normal), ripping off is another.

Comment: @patricksweeney No, that a free download template. Just when I downloaded it, it only came with 3 css files and a index. Whne I uploaded it it was missing tons of stuff

Answer (score 0):

Please check the licensing on the blog template before doing this...

Chrome developer tools let's you see what any webpage is made of. Do the following and it will help you find what is missing:

1. Visit the page in Chrome browser
2. Hit F12 (Google Dev Tools will show up on the right or on the bottom)
3. Click "Resources" tab
4. Go into Frames > [domain name]
5. You can see a list of everything that makes up the site including fonts, images, css, javascript, etc.

Follow the above steps for your working blog and then the blog you copied and compare the resources of each to see what you are missing.

In developer tools, if you click on "Console" tab you will see the errors that is causing your page not to load correctly (You may have already done this). But looking in the "Resources" tab will tell show you the actually code that you are missing.

I hope this helps.